# Defining android activity as dialog with light theme

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, themes

In my application I am defining one android activity as dialog.It looks proper.Only problem with that is my dialog appear in dark theme. I want to display it into light theme. I defined my activity dialog in following manner :

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.MinWidth"
    android:name="com.example.dialog"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_list" 
    >
</activity>
```

How to do this. Any solution. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use Holo Light Dialog theme:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
    android:name="com.example.dialog"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_list" />
```

Comment: Hi silvia_aut thank you for replay. But when I try this it showing ' Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.Light.Dialog').' How to solve this?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" this will run fine. If you want Light theme you have to create your own custom theme like RobinHood posted.

Comment: Maybe this can help you .. http://blog.andromo.com/2011/fixing-text-colours-on-an-alertdialog-when-using-theme-light/

Comment: Yeah I tired with  `@android:style/theme.holo.light.Dialog` and its working fine. Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

Way around is to define custom theme into style xml, check below code:-

Style:

```
<style name="Theme.D1NoTitleDim" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:background">#22000000</item>
</style>
```

manifest:

```
<activity
   android:theme="@style/Theme.D1NoTitleDim"
    android:name="com.example.dialog"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_list" 
    >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This also have worked for me. I have my app theme applied for the dialog activity.

```
<style name="Theme.UserDialog" parent="@style/MyAppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this may be help you**

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme_Wallpaper"
    android:name="com.example.dialog"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_list" 
    >
</activity>
```