# Android How to convert tab Fragment to popup window

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on tab Fragment.

[Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/swipable-navigation-tabs-using-actionbarcompat-library/) is the tutorial I have used to follow.

Now I want to display this fragment like a popup (display on parent window). Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: if you wish to show this whole thing as a dialog, try making it a dialog activity. Use this answer .http://stackoverflow.com/a/18525631/609782

if this is not what you want. Elaborate your answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer Darpan. What i want is show this tab window as a dialog box.