# Show a AlertDialog when I get a broadcast ? In SDK >= 23

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to do that: I can use `LoginActivity` login and into `MainActivity`, the `MainActivity` have a `Button`, when I click the `Button` to send a broadcast, activity will show a `AlertDialog`, when I click `OK`, it will finish all activities and go back to `LoginActivity`.

I have set `alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)`, and write `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` in manifest.xml, and it can run when the SDK < 23.But how to run it when SDK >＝ 23？or how should I do from my code?

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("You are forced to be offline. Please try to login again.");
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
                            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)){
                                ActivityCollector.finishAll();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            ActivityCollector.finishAll();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Better to use Activity as Dialog.

Comment: sorry, I'm a android beginer, Can you describe it clearly? Thx :D

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525407/defining-android-activity-as-dialog-with-light-theme. Create one actviity using this example, and start this activity as place of showing dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= 23){

   //Do what you want

} else{

}
```

Comment: I think I have write like that you say, Can you help me more clearly?thank you :D

Comment: If api version greater than 23 means you have to Show dialog konw.So check before the api version using that code.It will return what api version your device is using.Did you understand??

Comment: Yes, I know, but I had done it in my code which is I write. and I can't use it raghtly, Can you help me to solve it in my code.thx :D